# C++: Can std::tuple_size/tuple_element be specialized?

Tags: c++, c++17

Is specialization of `std::tuple_size` and `std::tuple_element` permitted for custom types?
I suppose it is, but I want to be absolutely sure, and I can't find any concrete information.

Example (namespaces, member functions and `get<I>` overloads omitted):

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct vector { T _data[N]; };

template<size_t I, typename T, size_t N>
constexpr T& get(vector<T,N>& vec) { return vec._data[I]; }

namespace std {
template<typename T, size_t N>
class tuple_size< vector<T,N> > : public std::integral_constant<size_t, N> { };
template<size_t I, typename T, size_t N>
class tuple_element< I, vector<T,N> > { public: using type = T; };
}
```

I need that for use with structured bindings:

```
void f(vector<T,3> const& vec)
{
    auto& [x,y,z] = vec;
    // stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Specializations for user-defined types are generally fine, and always have been. N4606, [namespace.std]/1:

> A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

For `tuple_size`, the requirements for the original template are specified in [tuple.helper]/1:

> All specializations of `tuple_size<T>` shall meet the `UnaryTypeTrait` requirements with a `BaseCharacteristic` of `integral_constant<size_t, N>` for some `N`.

`UnaryTypeTrait`, in turn, in [meta.rqmts]/1:

> A *UnaryTypeTrait* describes a property of a type. It shall be a class template that takes one template type argument and, optionally, additional arguments that help define the property being described. It shall be `DefaultConstructible`, `CopyConstructible`, and publicly and unambiguously derived, directly or indirectly, from its *BaseCharacteristic*, which is a specialization of the template `integral_constant`, with the arguments to the template `integral_constant` determined by the requirements for the particular property being described. The member names of the BaseCharacteristic shall not be hidden and shall be unambiguously available in the UnaryTypeTrait.

`tuple_element`'s requirements are specified in [tuple.helper]/6 and [meta.rqmts]/3, but in the interest of brevity I won't post them here. Suffice to say that it is indeed legal to specialize...

Comment: Note that doing so is required in C++1z to use the new `auto[a,b,c]` structured bindings feature.

Comment: Is there any way to define these in terms of a base class or common interface? I have a lot of `F<X...> ~= tuple<F<X>...>`, `G<S, Y...> ~= tuple<G<S, Y>...>`, etc., and if they did subclass tuples, I would still have to define `tuple_element<I, F<X...>>: tuple_element<I, tuple<F<X>...>>` and so on. All I can think of is opening up the generic `tuple_size<S>`/`tuple_element<I,S>` to using `size()` or base classes, which seems like asking for trouble. If I can't do better I'll have to use macros.

Comment: @John : Funny, I just bumped into the same issue literally yesterday. :-] Unfortunately I didn't come up with anything that didn't require minor intrusive changes to the trait, but I was in control of the traits in question so I didn't think about it too hard. I'd be interested to know if there turns out to be a clever non-intrusive solution!

Comment: @John : Here's a thought, using C++20: https://godbolt.org/z/5zrKE9 I can't think of a way to make this work non-intrusively (e.g. for structured bindings) without concepts though, so C++17 code may be out of luck.

Comment: Thank you so much! C++20 looks wild. One of my attempts was effectively `template<class T> struct tuple_size<enable_if_t<is_tuple<typename T::type>::value, T>>: ...` but sadly T couldn't be deduced. I guess that's what concepts are for. Quick question, isn't that `is_convertible<D*,B*>` technique used to avoid false negatives using `is_base_of<B,D>`? Why use both in conjunction?

Comment: @John : `is_base_of` returns true for privately- and ambiguously-inherited bases; since we want to delegate to `std::tuple`'s `tuple_size` and `tuple_element` without casting, we need to make sure our object is also implicitly-convertible to `tuple`. In this case the `is_base_of` check is actually a stronger check than we strictly need, as we could just check for the convertibility to additionally support types with a tuple member and an `operator std::tuple<...>&` rather than a tuple base, but I wanted the concept to describe `my_tuple_base` as closely as possible without actually naming it.